# Fields are null after portlet's form submission

Tags: java, portlet

I want to submit form with values and read them by action method in a portlet but the returned values are always null. Here is my code, but I don't see anything wrong here.

```
<portlet:actionURL name="calculate" var="calculateAction" />
    <form name="<portlet:namespace/>calculatorForm" action="${calculateAction}" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
         <table>
              <tr>
                 <td><label for="<portlet:namespace/>date">Date</label></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>date" id="<portlet:namespace/>date" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><label for="<portlet:namespace/>amount">Amount</label></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>amount" id="<portlet:namespace/>amount" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Calculate" /></td>
              </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and my method looks like this

```
@ProcessAction(name = "calculate")
public void calculate(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
    String stringDate = request.getParameter("date");
    String stringAmount = request.getParameter("amount");
    System.out.println("Amount: " + stringAmount);
    System.out.println("Date: " + stringDate);
}
```

Method is correctly called but both variables are always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have prepended the portlet namespace to each of your form inputs, you will need to call `getParameter` with the namespace as well. Try using

```
request.getParameter(response.getNamespace()+"data");
request.getParameter(response.getNamespace()+"amount");
```

Comment: I had the same error without the namespace. But I am definitely going to try this